# Presence of dynamic call inside a function prevents static context checking.Why?

Tags: c#, dynamic, static

I have the following code. Using Visual Studio 2013. Please note the dynamic function call in the function

```
class Someclass
{
   public static string[] BuildParametersString(ISomeInterface obj1, ISecondInterface obj2)
   {
      //.....

      var dt = obj1.GetDate();//this returns a dynamic type.
      SomeFunc(dt);//Run time error
   } 

   private string SomeFunc(DateTime somedate)
   {
     //......
   }
}
```

Runtime Error(at  SomeFunc(dt);): an object reference is required for a non-static field, method or property.

If I replace the following code

```
 var dt = obj1.GetDate();//this returns a dynamic type.
```

with this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
```

I am getting a compiler error (at  SomeFunc(dt))

Cannot access not static method SomeFunc in static context.

Any explanation to the behaviour?

Comment: Ahh, now we're getting somewhere. The use of `dynamic` here is causing the compiler to defer most compilation work until runtime. I suppose, in theory, the compiler could throw an exception here because (I think) there's no possible method that could run. (Or is there? Maybe some extension method? Can this assumption be made at compile time with regards to `dynamic`?) But basically, you're using `dynamic` so that throws all compile time checking/safety out the window and instead you get the error at runtime.

Comment: i think you have another method named `SomeFunc` which is static

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: Not necessarily. I whipped up this simple example and LINQPad and it definitely works (compiles) as-is without a static version of that method existing. EDIT: For example: `public static void Foo() { dynamic dt = DateTime.Now; Bar(dt); } private void Bar(DateTime somedate) { Console.WriteLine(somedate);} Foo();` This will compile fine, but at runtime throws the error.

Comment: but in my test (VS 2015) it doesn't work. i get the compile time error that cannot access non static. only i dont get error when one overload is static with same number of parameters(not same type). so there is possibility of calling static method. @ChrisSinclair Edit: Tested your example but still i get compile time error.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: Lovely! I'm doing it in LINQPad. Can't do a test in VS right now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overload resolution is still performed at compile time with `dynamic` to give a list of potential functions that could be called. At runtime, the list is narrowed down to the best according to the actual type of the `dynamic`.

According to the spec, however, overload resolution only considers the number and types of arguments - not `static` or even accessibility. According to some quick tests, it appears the order of operations at compile time is:

1. Accessibility checks
2. Overload resolution
3. Static check

Since `dynamic` affects overload resolution (step #2), but cannot narrow down to the best possible candidate at compile-time it appears that the `static` check (#3) is also deferred until runtime.

I don't see any reason in theory that the steps couldn't be reordered (NB: I don't know if there's a relevant spec to consider), or that step #3 couldn't be performed (at compile time) against all possible candidates coming out of the 'dynamic` overload resolution to ensure at least one candidate remains.

Even if it's not an actual bug<sup>1</sup>, I do think it goes against the design principle of `dynamic` - which I always understood to be to only defer what you have no choice but to defer.

UPDATE: Note that the C# 6 compiler in LINQPad 5/VS2015 now flags this at compile time; though the order of operations do not appear to have changed.

<sup>1</sup>The C# 5 spec section 7.6.5.1 (Method invocations) specifies that "final validation" (including static check) happens after overload resolution; section 7.5.4 (Compile-time checking of dynamic overload resolution) only specifies that partial type inference and partial applicability checks (overload resolution) are performed for method calls with dynamic argument.

Comment: It took a bit, but finally found a relevant @ericlippert post discussing the order (yes, it's bestness then staticness) and the reasons behind it (it's simpler). http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/06/color-color.aspx

Answer (score 0):

<s>Since `SomeFunc(DateTime)` has `DateTime` as it's parameter type you cannot give it a `dynamic` object. It expects a `DateTime`, so you have to typecast it.</s>
EDIT: actually, this is not true, as Chris Sinclair points out you can use `dynamic` like this. The rest of my answer still holds though

You also cannot access the instance method `SomeFunc(DateTime)` from a static method, since the instance method might rely on instance variables that do not exist in a static context. Either make `SomeFunc(DateTime)` static (if possible) or make `BuildParametersString(ISomeInterface, ISecondInterface)` an instance method (or just return the result from `GetDate()` and send it as an argument to `SomeFunc(DateTime)` from the client code.

I don't know if this is just an example to show a point, but I'd also SERIOUSLY reconsider using dynamic variables in this case. Do you gain anything from it? They should normally be avoided at all costs since they only complicate things and you lost all compile-time checks.

Comment: _"Since SomeFunc(DateTime) has DateTime as it's parameter type you cannot give it a dynamic object. It expects a DateTime, so you have to typecast it."_ That's not true. You can definitely pass a `dynamic` variable to it and it will compile and work fine if that dynamic variable is indeed assigned a `DateTime`.